# How to publish .net app for any framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010, publishing, .net-framework-version

I have created a program in VB.net 2010 and I want to publish it such that it works on any version of windows (7+). But when I use it on windows 10. It gives error because .net framework 3.5 is not installed. I want to make it such that it works on all windows platforms. I also don't want to make any type of installer. It should be direct running exe.

Comment: I don't believe this is achievable. That aside, you should try target the latest frameworks and use the latest IDE for the safest and best experience all round.

Comment: Windows 7 is end of life. If you want to support as many Windows releases as possible, write it in .NET Core and publish as win-x86 self contained. But that really gives you unnecessary limitation (of x86), and you can see none of the most popular Windows apps goes that way.